# Why I still having the following error: '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am trying to configure typesript to start a node project. I am doing the following steps:
Installing typescript:

- npm i --save-dev typescript

Installing ts-node:

- npm i --save-dev ts-node

Installing the types definition for node:

- npm i --save-dev @types/node

Adding the typescript configuration file:

- npx tsc --init

Go to my package.json file and update the script:
"build": "npx tsc"

Go to my tsconfig.json file and uncomment the library:

- change: // "lib": [], to: "lib": ["ES6"],
- Also change: // "outDir": "./", to a build folder: "outDir": "./build",
- Also uncomment: // "noImplicitAny": true,

Finally go to the end of the file and exclude the node_modules folder (right after the: "compilerOptions"):
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

When trying to compile the project to javascript by running:

- npm run build

I end up with the following error: "node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Note that I did verify if the npm Path was added in the Environment Variable.
And also that the **npm install is running successfully**, and when typing node in the terminal it returns: Welcome to Node.js v14.17.5.
Type ".help" for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **solve this problem in my case** by just running following command:-
 `npm i ts-node nodemon`

Answer (score 1):

Just run this and this issue is resulve

```
 npm install -g ts-node​
​ npm install -D tslib @types/node
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by opening the PowerShell command line and run the following:

- setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs"

Answer (score -1):

in my case
npm install -g ts-node​
​npm install -D tslib @types/node

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71494923/2409397